# How do I keep the value of the input text by using mask.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGUcj/253/). My problem is that if i write it wrong, for instance i write 9 characters (not 10 as it required) and if press the tab button from the keyboard, all of the 9 characters disappears and i have to write it again. What should I do ? how do i memorize the value ? 
This is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#Contact_phone").mask("9999-999-999");
});
```

and the HTML :

```
<input placeholder="telefon" name="x1" id="Contact_phone" type="text">
<input placeholder="other*" name="x2" id="other" type="text">
```

Comment: yes, that's what mask is for, you could store in temporary array on key events.

Comment: can you post me an example please ?

Comment: I have updated your link by removing some events, check here and let me know if it works? http://jsfiddle.net/EGUcj/254/

Comment: it works, can you tell me which are that lines of code ?

Comment: I have removed the alternate events of `focusin` &  `focusout`